# Simulating a loose "document-based" schema with SQL

Tags: sql

I am looking at using a SQL software to store and query objects with a **loose schema**.

We know that an object corresponds to a row of an SQL table, and it's attributes correspond to columns. By 'loose schema', I mean that **an object can have attributes that are not hardwired to the table's (rather tables') structure**. An arbitrary (attribute,value) can be attached to an object.

---

Let me illustrate with a specific example:

For the given objects:

```
<subject>
name:data structures
tag:CS 
description:easy
desired_seniority:5.0

<subject>
name:microprocessors
tag:CS,electronics        <multi-valued
description:easy
desired_seniority:5.5     <numeric
```

and

```
<teacher>
name:John Doe
tag:electronics
seniority:5.8
```

The query will be

```
For each teacher, 
return all subjects whose tags match and 
whose desired seniority is less than or equal to the teacher's
```

The teacher *'John Doe'* will be matched with subject *'microprocessors'* because they share the tag *'electronics'* and his seniority *5.8* is greater than the subject's desired seniority *5.5*

Note that I have used **numeric** (queries do comparison) and **multi-valued** (queries do an 'is in' match) string in the strings.

---

**What exactly:** I am looking for the right data model and corresponding queries that lets me simulate a loose schema on a SQL software.

---

I accept these constraints:

1. teacher and subject may be described by *distinct* tables
2. there will be one to one correspondence of attributes (if a query uses attribute 'x', all rows have attribute 'x1' and 'x2' of same type)

---

I saw http://www.igvita.com/2010/03/01/schema-free-mysql-vs-nosql/ and https://github.com/jamesgolick/friendly .

---

Yes, there are NoSQL databases and special ORMs. We use [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) (it's great!). But I would avoid increasing the complexity of the project by including them. The performance overhead of emulating a noSQL store is not a concern.

Comment: If you want a document schema, use a document NoSQL store.  Trying to do a non-relational schema in SQL is possible but will never be as fast or efficient as a NoSQL solution - they exist for a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySql I would use something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `subject` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `desired_seniority` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;


INSERT INTO `subject` (`id`, `name`, `description`, `desired_seniority`) VALUES
(1, 'data structures', 'easy', 5.00),
(2, 'microprocesors', 'easy', 5.50);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `subject_tag` (
  `subject_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`subject_id`,`tag_id`),
  KEY `fk_subject_tag_tags` (`tag_id`),
  KEY `fk_subject_tag_subject` (`subject_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `subject_tag` (`subject_id`, `tag_id`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(2, 1),
(2, 2);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tag` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;


INSERT INTO `tag` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'CS'),
(2, 'Electronics');


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `teacher` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `surname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `seniority` decimal(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;


INSERT INTO `teacher` (`id`, `name`, `surname`, `seniority`) VALUES
(1, 'John', 'Doe', 5.80),
(2, 'John', 'Brown', 5.30);



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `teacher_tag` (
  `teacher_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`teacher_id`,`tag_id`),
  KEY `fk_teacher_tag_tag1` (`tag_id`),
  KEY `fk_teacher_tag_teacher` (`teacher_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `teacher_tag` (`teacher_id`, `tag_id`) VALUES
(1, 2);


ALTER TABLE `subject_tag`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_subject_tag_tag` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tag` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_subject_tag_subject` FOREIGN KEY (`subject_id`) REFERENCES `subject` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `teacher_tag`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_teacher_tag_tag` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tag` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_teacher_tag_teacher` FOREIGN KEY (`teacher_id`) REFERENCES `teacher` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

And to get teachers with matched subjectes:

```
SELECT t.surname, t.name, GROUP_CONCAT( s.name SEPARATOR ' | ' ) AS subject_name
FROM teacher t
JOIN teacher_tag tt ON tt.teacher_id = t.id
JOIN subject_tag st ON st.tag_id = tt.tag_id
JOIN subject s ON st.subject_id = s.id
AND s.desired_seniority <= t.seniority
GROUP BY t.id
```

Comment: I did intend for a loose schema, there are both teacher and subject objects, but their attributes can be 'inserted', not depend on the tables' static schema (I edited para 1 to better explain). I will check this out in detail next day.

Comment: Ok if I understand correctly you should add `teacher_atrr (teacher_id, attr_name, 'atrr_value')` and `subject_attr (subject_id, attr_name, attr_value)` tables to db scheme. Those tables gives you a place where you can dynamically add attributes for teachers and subjects without changing tables structures.